# How to add subarrays to itself? Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, addition, sub-array

I have an array containing of subarrays like this:

```
arr = [[{"big" => "2055", "small" => -"-10", "thin" => "i"},
        {"big" => "2785", "small" => "0", "thin" => "l"}], 
       [{"big" => "7890", "small" => "3", "thin" => "t"},
        {"big" => "2669", "small" => "0,5", "thin" => "f"},
        {"big" => "9000", "small" => "2", "fat" => "O"}]]
```

I want to add subarrays to itself to get an array like this:

```
arr = [{"big" => "2055", "small" => "-10", "thin" => "i"},
       {"big" => "2785", "small" => "0", "thin" => "l"},
       {"big" => "7890", "small" => "3", "thin" => "t"},
       {"big" => "2669", "small" => "0,5", "thin" => "f"},
       {"big" => "9000", "small" => "2", "fat" => "O"}]
```

Doing like this:

```
arr.map! {|x| x+x}
```

I get added subarrays but every hash appears twice. How to do it right?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to [flatten](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten) the array?

```
arr.flatten
```

It concatenates every sub-array into one big array, recursively if needed.

```
[[1,2], [3,4]].flatten
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you want to modify the array in place, you can use :

```
arr.flatten!
```

It doesn't matter what the inner-elements look like (integers, strings, hashes), as long as they're not arrays, they won't be touched by `flatten`.

Comment: And even if they are arrays, `flatten` accepts a `level` parameter :) `[[1,[2]],[3,[4]]].flatten(1) #⇒ [1, [2], 3, [4]]`.

Comment: @mudasobwa: True, but I should have just closed the question instead of answering it.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby have a built in method try use [Array.flatten](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`flatten!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten-21):

```
arr.flatten!

#=> [{"big"=>"2055", "small"=>"-10", "thin"=>"i"},
     {"big"=>"2785", "small"=>"0", "thin"=>"l"},
     {"big"=>"7890", "small"=>"3", "thin"=>"t"},
     {"big"=>"2669", "small"=>"0,5", "thin"=>"f"},
     {"big"=>"9000", "small"=>"2", "fat"=>"O"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
arr = arr.flatten
```